# JPanel not honouring setMinimumSize / ComponentListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel which should not be reduced less than the minimum size but it's not doing that. I understand that I should use a ComponentListener which I have implemented but still no use.

Can someone explain what's is going wrong programmatically?

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
public class ResearchdbView extends JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;

private ResearchdbView() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {     
    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    mainPanel.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(880, 700));
    mainPanel.setMaximumSize(null);
    mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(880, 700));
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(880, 700));
    setResizable(true);
    mainPanel.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
            mainPanel.setSize((Math.max(880, mainPanel.getWidth())), Math.max(700, mainPanel.getHeight()));
        }
    });

    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);      
}}
```

PS. I have tried all solutions from similar posts to reach here.

Comment: The BorderLayout ignores all your size suggestions. When you add a component to the CENTER of the BorderLayout, the component will simply take all the space available in the frame. Some layout managers, like the BoxLayout I think, will respect the minimum size of a component. The component will just get truncated. Not really sure what you are trying to achieve, so I can't make any other suggestion.

Comment: The size and placement of your widgets is up to the layout manager. Sure you can give the layout manager some hints with preferred size and minimum size but don't complain when he ignores you. The default layout is BorderLayout. Read more on that and and layouts in general.

Comment: If you want to limit the size of the window, you can call `setMinimumSize` on the `JFrame`, which should work. You would need to calculate the correct size ahead of time, or call `frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize())` the first time it's made visible (with e.g. a `WindowListener`).

Comment: @Radiodef Thank you for your comment, it actually led me to the solution. If you write this as an answer I will gladly accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

BorderLayout does not respect any of those size hints for components placed in the CENTER.

For the different borders, it depends on what size you're setting. NORTH and SOUTH respect the **preferred** height (but ignore width). WEST and EAST respects **preferred** width and ignore height. The other size hints are ignored.

EDIT: Check out this site, it has a nice table outlining what the different Layout Managers do with those hints. https://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-layout-manager-sizing/

I tried to find one in the javadocs but couldn't find this info aggregated in a single space.

Comment: What should be used instead of BorderLayout.CENTER? Also it has nothing to do with the JFrame? (Sorry I'm just getting a hang of swing.)

Comment: The Swig tutorial has a section on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). It is the place to start for Swing basics.

Comment: @labmat the content pane in JFrame is setup with a BorderLayout by default. You can change it if you like, just call setLayout on the content pane and set it to something like FlowLayout